# What can I do for Gmail emails stop going to Spam?

Tags: email, gmail, email-spam

I have come across different solutions for this problem, but none have worked for me.  When a user registers in my website, we automatically send him a "Verify your account" email which has a button and at the footer there is a link to our website. When the user clicks the button, he is directed to our website. We're using gmail with our domain email (@mydomain.com), and we can see that over 50% of emails go directly to Spam. We have worked around a couple of solutions, but none are working. We don't want to use a service such as SendGrid.

This is how we create and send our emails (step by step)

1. We created an html/css email using a [Zurb's template](https://get.foundation/emails/email-templates.html).
2. We used the [Zurb Email Inliner](https://get.foundation/emails/inliner.html) to make the CSS inline.
3. We use the [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about) library to send the emails
4. Finally, the messages are signed using DKIM

As I've mentioned before, most emails end up in Spam. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.1 First have only the DKIM is pretty much useless if you don’t also have an SPF as they work in conjunction:

- [Ensure mail delivery & prevent spoofing (SPF)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en)
- [Generate a DKIM key for your domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174126?hl=en)

> .2  **[Then you need to Set up an outbound mail gateway](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178333?hl=en)**

Furthermore take not of this:

- An incorrectly set Auto forwarding or routing setting. Like dual delivery or automatic responses.
- Enter in the field "CC" or "BCC" when composing a message with too many email addresses at a time.
- Not having the SPF and DKIM values set correctly.
- Recipient addresses mark your emails as Spam, includes either a manual action or an automatic action such as a filter they have enabled or a device (very often phones) that automatically marks as Spam.

Also important to note that  **you shouldn’t use HTML and CSS**  to hide content in your messages. Hiding content might cause messages to be marked as spam. as explain in this article (and I suggest you to read it through):

.1  [follow best practices for sending to Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126)

---

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that you can run some test if you send email to Gmail using  [The Postmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9981691?visit_id=637328352606997612-2387040301&rd=1)

keep in mind that is only towards Gmail account, but you can open few free one for test purposes

---

---

Any other questions feel free to ask

Comment: This is great. I will forward this to my team and I'll let you know if we need rescue. :)

Comment: Sure Paula any question, if you thing the answer is correct maybe you want to approve it ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was following all guidelines, had SPF, DKIM and DMARC properly setup etc etc. But still my emails were triggering the gmail spam filters.

Eventually, I noticed some images I had in the email that were served from AWS were the ones to trigger spam filters. The solution I found was rearranging the structure of the URL.

For example, if the image was stored in a bucket called "images" like so: https://images.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reviews.png it would trigger the spam filter

But if I access the image using its path style access, it would pass all the spam filters without issues, like this:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/reviews.png

In this case, the same image is stored in the same location, same bucket, I'm just accessing it in a different way (AWS accepts both of these ways as valid)

I'm not sure if you are using image URLs from AWS in your email, but you could try removing the images first and seeing if it's still landing in spam folder. With that you can at least know if the fault is in the URLs or something else you might be missing.

I have no idea why this works, but I can reliably pass all spam filters with this fix. If I revert to the original structure, all spam filters get triggered again.

Hope it helps, in my case, it took me weeks to figure out the issue triggering spam filters was just the image URLs and their structure.